# Python dataclasses inheritance part of attributes from parent dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I constructed multiple base `dataclass`. Now I want to construct a child `dataclass` inheriting from these base classes, but may inherit part of attributes defined in some base classes. Examples can be:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int = None
    b: float = None
    c: str = None

@dataclasses.dataclass
class B:
    d: int = None
    b: float = 3.5

@dataclasses.dataclass
class C:
    e: int = None
    f: float = 3.5
    g: int = None

@dataclasses.dataclass
class D(A, B):
    def __post_init__(self):
        for _field, _field_property in C.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if _field != "g":
                setattr(self, _field, _field_property.default)
```

Namely, I want to construct a child class `D` inheriting `A` and `B`, and attributes in `C` except `g`. Checking the child class `D`

```
>>> D.__dataclass_fields__.keys() # got dict_keys(['d', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
>>> d = D(a=4, b=2, c=5, d=3.4, e=2.1, g=55)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    d = D(a=4, b=2, c=5, d=3.4, e=2.1, g=55)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'e'
```

And

```
>>> D.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['__module__', '__post_init__', '__doc__', '__dataclass_params__', '__dataclass_fields__', '__init__', '__repr__', '__eq__', '__hash__'])
```

When I changed `__post_init__` to `__init__` and using `super().__init__()` for the inheritance, still can't the attributes from class `C` and lose the advantage of `dataclass`, i.e.,

```
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
class D(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for _field, _field_property in C.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if _field != "g":
                setattr(self, _field, _field_property.default)
```

And run

```
>>> d = D(a=4, b=2, c=5, d=3.4, e=2.1, g=55)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    d = D(a=4, b=2, c=5, d=3.4, e=2.1, g=55)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

What should I do?

Comment: I've bumped into this too and I don't think `dataclasses` really supports inheritance.

Comment: Create class `C'` that is like `C` without the `g` attribute, `C` becomes a subclass of `C'` adding the new `g` attribute, and your `D` inherits `A,B, C'`. Dataclasses work at *class creation time*, `__post_init__` works at *instance creation time*, i.e. **way** too late to modify the definition of `__init__`

Comment: It's good that you found a working solution, but you should also consider using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). In the case you're presenting, it looks like class `D` might be better off having instances of `A`, `B`, and maybe `C_part` instead of inheriting them.

Answer (score 1):

Similar as what proposed by @GiacomoAlzetta, I suddenly come out that idea using `dataclasses.make_dataclass`, i.e., generate a copy of `C` but excluding attribute `g`, i.e.,

```
<<< C_part = dataclasses.make_dataclass("C_part", [(_field, _field_property.type, _field_property.default) for _field, _field_property in C.__dataclass_fields__.items() if _field != "g"])
```

Thus I have

```
>>> C_part.__dataclass_fields__.keys()  # dict_keys(['e', 'f'])
```

Then the `D` can be obtained by

```
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
class D(A, B, C_part):
    pass

>>> d = D(a=4, b=2, c=5, d=3.4, e=2.1, f=55)
>>> d
D(e=2.1, f=55, d=3.4, b=2, a=4, c=5)
```